# Find Object in Array in Node js and mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my data:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b8abaaaaffeaa2b9c77b6b8"), 
"user_id" : "ddddddddd", 
"data" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ab6e57ffe8b2b9c77b6b9"), 
        "data1" : "qqqq", 
        "fr" : "qqqq"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ab719406d7235240f4338"), 
        "data1" : "III", 
        "fr" : "III"
    }
]
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I wand find Object by _id  in data , but I want to search through Array of data and I use this code but it doesn't work:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var o_id = new ObjectID("5b8ab719406d7235240f4338");
array.find({'_id'  :o_id}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

I want to access III in this data.

Comment: Usually mongodb query is formatted like [db_name].[collection_name].[operation].
What is array?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ab719406d7235240f4338"), 
        "data1" : "III", 
        "fr" : "III"
    }

Comment: i dont want to use for ,while ,.....
i want to solve it with mongoose